# 400 Bad request when trying to post to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend

I'm putting together a simple todo list app using the MERN stack. My create-todo function suddenly stopped working, getting the console error of 400 bad request. I don't remember making any changes to that part of the code, it started after adding user registration/login. Here's my code:

Controller

```
  Todo.create(req.body)
      .then((data) => {
          console.log({ data });
          res.json({ message: "todo added successfully", data });
      })
      .catch((err) =>
          res.status(400).json({
              message: "unable to add new todo",
              error: err.message,
          })
      );
};
```

end point

```
/**
 * @route PUT api/todo/:id
 * @description update todo
 * @access public
 */
```

front-end

```
    const [data, setData] = useState({ title: "", description: "" });

    function handleChange(e) {
        setData((data) => ({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        axios
            .post("http://localhost:8000/api/todo", data)
            .then((res) => {
                setData({ title: "", description: "" });
                console.log(res.data.message);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error couldn't create TODO");
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Request failed with status code 400